# How to send Euro Sign or German ü sign over HTTP?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, http

I have created an API using ASP.Net/c#.Net which is used to send Text message to mobile phones. So, now my requirement is to send Euro Sign or German ü sign to the mobile phone. I am receiving the Text through HTTP for example:

```
 msg = Request.QueryString["msg"].ToString().Trim();
```

So, here I am getting whatever I send. When I am sending Euro sign then I am sending after URL Encoding so I receive what I get but when sending to the mobile phone I am getting b$ for euro sign and C< for ü sign.

I am encoding euro sign as below:

```
 %E2%82%AC
```

And ü sign as below:

```
  %C3%BC
```

But still I am not getting the sign. Please help me on this I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `&#8364;` for Euro and `&#252;` for ü.

Comment: HTML encoding has really nothing to do with HTTP.